# How to write delay without sleep for WebElement if the element is still not loaded?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write auto tests for web app and I have a problem with delay. I don't want to use sleeps in my script, so I wrote the next:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("MyClassName")).Displayed
```

With if it works ok (also, Enabled can be used), but I have few views were loading getting 3-5 seconds, so I received NoSuchElementException, because it tries to find element, and the element is still not loaded.
I know that the problem can be solved by adding simple sleep, but I don't want to do it.

Are there any other solutions, except sleep?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Place your code into an async task and do `await Task.Delay(nnn);`

Comment: I've removed the tags from the title of this question and your new question since it goes against this site's tagging guidelines (which state that you should not place tags in the question title unless they're organically part of a sentence).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. You can change the method time if you like or even make it a variable and pass a value to it.

```
    call - WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime("//a[@class='myClass");

    public static void WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(value)).Displayed);
        }
        catch (Exception) 
         { 
           //add error handling;
           throw; 
         }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Still NoSuchElementException, it does not wauit, just throw an exeption. Actually, this is the problem. It takes takes time for system to load the page with the element.

Comment: How much time are we talking? If you add the thread sleep in, does it work? If the sleep works, you know your element is good. You can also try looking for a different element on the page that is loaded at the same time. Is the element you are looking for in an iframe by chance?

Comment: Actually, I guess that I did something wrong.
Sleeps work fine, I set it to 10 sec.
It does not wait enough, so I receive or NoSuchElement or Element is not clickable.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure in C# but in python we had expected conditions and wait untill class.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(),"Enter a gift card, voucher or promotional code")]'))).click()
```

above command will wait for 30 sec before throwing error and check the mentioned element is available to click or not for every 0.5 sec.

Check for EC(expected condition) and wait untill API in c# selenium module